# YouCompleteMe Clang Support Mavericks

Tags: macos, vim, clang, osx-mavericks

I installed YouCompleteMe for VIM via Vundle on my Mac with Mavericks. After Vundle did its magic i ran

```
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

which worked without any errors. The Python completion works fine, too. But the C Lang Family support does not seem to work. Also running

```
./run_tests.sh
```

gives me

```
Your C++ compiler supports C++11, compiling in that mode.
-- Found PythonLibs:        /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (found suitable version "2.7.7", minimum required is "2.6")
NOT using libclang, no semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC will be available
```

Does anybody know how to solve that problem?

Comment: By asking on the plugin's issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the 2nd command

```
./run_tests.sh
```

It's will re-compile ycm_*.so without --clang-completer (that is default option).

To fix it, install again:

```
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

Answer (score 0):

add your clang_library_path in .vimrc,such as

```
let g:clang_library_path='/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/'
```